# YII2 view - Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста. Вроде бы сделано все по мануалу, но, что-то я не понимаю. Раньше работал с yii 1, сейчас возможно не совсем понимаю применение use.

**Лезет ошибка Class 'yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice' not found**

composer.json

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.5",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*"
},
```

config/web.php

```
        'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
          'facebook' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
            'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
            'clientId' => '***',
            'clientSecret' => '***',
          ],
        ],
      ],
```

view/index.php

```
          use yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice;
          <?=yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
             'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth'],
             'popupMode' => true,
        ]); ?>
```

сам файл в наличии: 
/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/widgets/AuthChoice.php

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/212773/
Как по мне доступно про неймспейсы, может немного прояснит.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вместо `yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget`:
 либо `AuthChoice::widget` либо `\yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget` .
 Во втором случае команда `use` - необязательна.

Если не поможет - надо смотреть autoloader - дебажить его, смотреть пути, по которым пытается затянуться класс.

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю всех за советы!

Дело было в том что extension я устанавливал на прямую "по старому", а не через Composer.

Answer (score -1):

Для тех, кто все же ставит расширения вручную (бывает нужно, если нет доступа к консоли и пр.) - в `vendor\yiisoft\extensions.php` прописать подобным к остальным образом.